# How to receive broadcast locations in an activity?

Tags: android

I've built an IntentService to collect location data in the background (with the user's knowledge). It uses a PendingIntent to receive locations, rather than a LocationListener. I receive locations fine in the receiver.

But how do I pick up these locations from an Activity? Can I receive the location broadcasts directly, or do I need to send a new type of broadcast for activities to receive?

Service:

```
    Intent activeIntent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) (App.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_TIME_CHANGE, LOCATION_DISTANCE_CHANGE, pendingIntent);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_TIME_CHANGE, LOCATION_DISTANCE_CHANGE, pendingIntent);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, LOCATION_TIME_CHANGE, LOCATION_DISTANCE_CHANGE, pendingIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    Location loc = (Location)b.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    // TODO handle the location here
}
```

Comment: You can use Public Variables of a public class to be updated and accessed elsewhere

Comment: Well how would the activity know when to read them?

Comment: That would not be an efficient approach but is simply possible By Asynchrously checking whether values are changed or not in that activity..

Comment: You Can define a static class to receive the updates inside your code. Or try SharedPreferences to Hold them.

Comment: These suggestions are not acceptable solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the same broadcast event.

Define a more generic action for your intent.

```
Intent activeIntent = new Intent("com.mypackage.myproduct.ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGED");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
```

Then, register `LocationReceiver` in your Manifest with that action as the filter. This way you will always receive the broadcast in your `LocationReceiver`.

Finally, to get the broadcast in your Activities, register/unregister an anonymous broadcast receiver (again, with your action as a filter) in onResume/onPause.

Comment: Brilliant, easy when you know how. Thanks.